# How To Changed Back icon and label on action bar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design

i've been trying to changed the back button and label, other post said we can

user  but it didn't work

[There is supposed to be there but the color was white so we can't see them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEN5Y.png)

Comment: welcome to SO. first please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and correct your question. without code samples we will not help you.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]